# Create & download a file on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to create an excel file (based on some data that are on the server) and download it. All of this when a button is triggered.

What I did for now is to create an HTML button that calls a javascript function. 
This javascript function makes an AJAX call to a PHP file that creates the excel file through the library "Spreadsheet" and then supposed to download it.

The excel file is created in the server but the download isn't triggered.

HTML side :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="downloadExcel()">
```

Javascript side :

```
function downloadExcel(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'download.php',
    type : "POST",
    data : { action: "create_sheet"}
});
}
```

PHP side :

```
$action = (string)$_POST['action']; 

if("create_sheet" == $action) {
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $writer->save('myExcel.xlsx');

    ob_clean();
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename="myExcel.xlsx"');
    $writer->save("php://output");
    exit;
}
```

The excel file is created but the download isn't triggered.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help !

EDIT : When I delete the condition on the PHP side and call the download.php as suggested with : 
          `<a href="download.php">DL</a>`
It works
Thank you

Comment: Try putting `$writer->save("php://output");` before the header statements.

Comment: Also why ajax? You want the file to be saved on the user's computer. no?

Comment: @mplungjan the save("php://output") doesn't download on the user's computer?

Comment: @Thefourthbird it doesn't change anything

Comment: Not if you Ajax it

Comment: @mplungjan i don't understand, what should I do?

Comment: Don’t use JS for this

Comment: Like mplungjan said, just create a link to donwload.php and remove the check for "create_sheet" in the php

Comment: there is no need to use ajax here as you are not posting any data that is required to craete excel ,instead of using ajax u can directly redirect to download.php  . using <a href tag , try doing this.